# Webview video does not play in HTML with custom URL like data://

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have html snippet coming from server which looks like

```
<p class="">This is a sample new article.</p>
<p class="">Now a video.</p>
<div class="medium-insert-embeds" contenteditable="false">
<figure>
    <div class="medium-insert-embed">
        <div><div>
        <iframe src="cdn.iframe.ly/api/iframe?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%embed%3Fv%3DRi7-vnrJD3k&amp;key=318566b7c368a42be5c813bdc415b817" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no"></iframe></div></div>
    </div>
</figure>
</div>
```

Note youtube URL scheme in above. I am setting up my webview as following

```
wbFulltext.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
wbFulltext.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wbFulltext.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
wbFulltext.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I have also tried using `loadDataWithBaseURL` with `null` base url. But nothing works I cannot even see the thumbnail of video in webview forget about playing it.

Same HTML response from API works fine in iOS.

Comment: I tried changing the iframe with directly from youtube and it seemed to work

Comment: yeah but this is what I am getting from API and somehow it seems to work in iOS webview.